# Unable to install GCC using anaconda

Tags: python, gcc, anaconda

This is output of the command `conda install gcc`:

```
    Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - gcc-6
```

Comment: try conda install -c anaconda gcc

Comment: Getting the same error

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure how exactly the packages relate, but I needed to install the `gcc` package to resolve some sort of load error. Given that `gcc` didn't produce any results, I ran a quick

```
$ conda search gcc
```

Which yielded, among other things, `gcc_linux-64`. After

```
$ conda install gcc_linux-64
```

My issue went away, despite the fact that `which gcc` still pointed to the system install ‍♂️

Comment: FYI, "which gcc" command will find the first occurrence of gcc, Can you show your path environment to troubleshoot? I.E. `env | grep PATH`. The first entry in the output should be the location of your currently activated conda environment: `PATH=path_to_conda/envs/my_active_env`, if it isn't then you need to check on that issue.

Comment: In my case, I had to `cd ~/miniconda3/bin` then, `ln -s x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc gcc`

Comment: @EduardoReis: That will fix gcc, do you also know the solution for fixing g++?

Comment: @user3015703, just create another symbolic link. Something like `ln -s x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cpp c++` should work.

Answer (score 10):

I had to install two conda packages to fix this issue:

```
$ conda install gcc_linux-64
$ conda install gxx_linux-64
```

Comment: great! Thanks a lot. Running only the first one didn't work, but both did the job.